# Android Facebook SDK3.0, session state OPENING

Tags: android, facebook

I am trying to use the Facebook SDK 3.0 to retrieve an access token on button press in my android app. I have a generic button in my Activity that is doing the following:

```
Button facebook = (Button)findViewById(R.id.facebookLoginButton);
    facebook.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Session session = new Session(getApplicationContext());
            Session.setActiveSession(session);
            session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(SignInActivity.this).setCallback(statusCallback));
        }
    });
```

And then the callback:

```
private class FacebookSessionStatusCallback implements Session.StatusCallback {
    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
            String s=session.getAccessToken();
    }
}
```

Clicking the button prompts me for my permission to access my profile as expected, but this callback is only ever called once with SessionState as "OPENING". The state doesn't change after this.

What am I missing here? My end goal is really just to get an access token once, and I don't really care about persisting the session or using it to log into my app.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You need to override the onActivityResult so that after the credentials are checked against Facebook for Android (or an inline login) the results are handled and the session updated. Add the following code:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Session.getActiveSession()
        .onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Comment: That was a quick fix, thanks! Quick follow up question-How can I set the requestCode so that I can check if it came from Facebook or not in onActivityResult?

Comment: See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/3.0/Session.OpenRequest but you would do something like: session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(SignInActivity.this).setCallback(statusCallback).setRequestCode(200)); then check the code 200 in this example.

Comment: If I'm using UiLifecycleHelper, would this still be necessary? I have overridden the onActivityResult but just put `uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);` but I got the same issue, then, I tried this solution but the result is the same.

Comment: @vida, yes when using UiLifecycleHelper you need to call onActivityResult(). Make sure you're calling super.onActivityResult() before calling the method on your UiLifecycleHelper instance.

Comment: @CAbernathy Got my issue fixed by doing this solution but on my Activity instead of my fragment alone. Thank you so much!

Comment: What if this doesn't solve it? I'm already overriding onActivityResult but still my session keeps alternating between OPENING and CLOSED_LOGIN_FAILED...?

Comment: Just a hint for anyone that implemented FacebookAuthentication as part of an AsyncTask: you implement onActivityResult as above on the Activity being acted upon. Still applicable as of SDK v3.5. Thank you for the hint!

Answer (score 1):

@Lucas Jota: Try changing request code. this works for me.
 session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(LoginActivity.this).setCallback(statusCallback).setRequestCode(urRequestCode));
Also, assure that your activity doesn't have "single instance" as property.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder "assure that your activity doesn't have "single instance" as property. I tried to use a singleton class, turned out that the second time I log in, the onActivityResult is not called.

Comment: @Yu Lu Your comment is Life Saver.. I was doing everything right but still had issues. In my manifest I had set noHistory="true" that was causing the problem.