# cannot login with the new 3.0 version of facebook sdk for android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I see there's a new version of Facebook SDK (3.0) that deprecates the old *Facebook* class and introduces a new way of logging in using the *Session* class.

I quickly wrote a simple app using the new login API:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private Session mFacebookSession;

private StatusCallback fbStatusCallback = new StatusCallback() {
    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        Log.v("dbg", "state: " + state);
        Log.v("dbg", "session: " + session);
    }
};

public void bc(View view)
{
    mFacebookSession = Session.openActiveSession(this, true, fbStatusCallback);
}
//etc..
}
```

The callback should get called twice, first for destroying the actual session token and second for getting a new access token.
Of course, my app id is set as a meta-data in my manifest file, etc.

When I execute the code, the Facebook Login dialog appears, I input my username and password and then it closes.

However, in my log I only see this:

```
01-17 03:28:01.587: V/dbg(7002): state: OPENING
01-17 03:28:01.587: V/dbg(7002): session: {Session state:OPENING, token:{AccessToken token:ACCESS_TOKEN_REMOVED permissions:[]}, appId:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx}
```

As a result, if I try to call *mFacebookSession.getAccessToken()* i get an empty string (not null).

What seems to be the problem?

**HOW I SOLVED THIS (LATER)**

I have overridden onActivityResult and called *Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);*

Comment: Are you 100% confident your appID is correct and you have set up the facebook app correctly? I had a similar problem and it came down to me using the id of another of my facebook apps

Comment: Well, the login dialog displays my application name and if I add some permissions (i also found a way to add them but didn't include in this code to keep things simple for everybody to understand), they are also displayed correctly.

Comment: hmm.. I now realize that in the *Native Android App' section I didn't put any hash. But why don't I get an Exception via the callback?

Comment: I honestly don't know, I wasn't getting any exceptions either. At least you found your answer

Comment: Well, I also added the hash but didn't in fact change anything. I'm still out of ideas unfortunately.

Comment: Did you also override the onActivityResult method in your MainActivity class, and call Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(...)?

Comment: I already figured that out:) Too bad your answer didn't came more quickly, before I bashed my brains for many hours:(

Comment: @Sterpu Mihai: I made the same your mistake: forgot to call onActivityResult()

Comment: Note: override `onActivityResult` in the *activity*, I was scratching my head for a while as it didn't work with me override `onActivityResult` in a fragment.

Answer (score 1):

Im just going to put this here for anyone else:

The Facebook SDK is really terrible at letting you know you have forgotten something. If it's not working for you double check your Facebook app and make sure you haven't forgotten something or put in the wrong values. In my case the appID was wrong in Sterpu Mihai's case it was the hash key

Comment: I don't know it's the hash, I didn't test it:) I'll post any update when I know for sure

Comment: I also found this on a forum: *I have not been able to get hash key for android but facebook seems to be working eitherway* :)

Answer (score 0):

another thing that would cause the same error (Token_removed)

[Android Facebook SDK3.0, session state OPENING](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13885521/android-facebook-sdk3-0-session-state-opening/21831076#21831076)