# Android facebook SDK authentification don't work

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

I am using latest android SDK. Dialog is opened, but after enter credentials dialog is closing and status don't change.

```
private StatusCallback statusCallback = new StatusCallback() {
    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        if (session.isOpened()) // call just one time and state is "opening"
            authWithToken("facebook", session.getAccessToken());
    }
};

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(new View(this));

    //setVisible(false);

    Settings.addLoggingBehavior(LoggingBehavior.CACHE);
    Settings.addLoggingBehavior(LoggingBehavior.INCLUDE_ACCESS_TOKENS);
    //Settings.addLoggingBehavior(LoggingBehavior.INCLUDE_RAW_RESPONSES);
    //Settings.addLoggingBehavior(LoggingBehavior.REQUESTS);

    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();

    if (session == null) {
        session = new Session.Builder(this).build();
        Session.setActiveSession(session);
    }

    if (!session.isOpened()) {
        Session.OpenRequest openRequest = new Session.OpenRequest(this);
        openRequest.setPermissions(permissions);
        openRequest.setLoginBehavior(SessionLoginBehavior.SSO_WITH_FALLBACK);
        openRequest.setCallback(statusCallback);
        session.openForPublish(openRequest); //here dialog is opened, user is able to enter credentials 
    }

    if (session != null && session.isOpened()) {
        if (!hasEmailPermission()) {
            NewPermissionsRequest request = new NewPermissionsRequest(this, permissions);
            request.setCallback(statusCallback);
            request.setLoginBehavior(SessionLoginBehavior.SSO_WITH_FALLBACK);

            session.requestNewReadPermissions(request);
        }
    }

    if (session != null && session.isOpened())
        authWithToken("facebook", session.getAccessToken());
}

private boolean hasEmailPermission() {
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    return session != null && session.getPermissions().containsAll(permissions);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    //never call this method 
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

I am did everything by facebook oficial "getting started" documentation

[Android Facebook SDK3.0, session state OPENING](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13885521/android-facebook-sdk3-0-session-state-opening)

doesn't work, because Facebook authentification dialog never calls onActivityResult()

Facebook application is not installed.

**UPDATE:**

I checked. `session.openForPublish(openRequest);` closes my activity and open Facebook Dialog. But why?

Comment: what exactly happen when you login did it try prompt to ask authorization first before closing or after you login it closes the dialog ?

Comment: Activity is closed just after facebook prompt to ask autorization. My activity don't get `onActivityResult` at all, because it is closed before.

Comment: so what do you want to achieve after user prompt user to ask for authorization? ask permission ?

Comment: I just need determine user complete autorization or not. I am stuck here, because I dont understand, why my application is closed. Other things I will try to make myself.

Comment: of course it will automatically closed after the user authorize because you need to get back to your application. are you using openSession?

Comment: No, you don't understand. Then I open facebook dialog my activity is instant closed automatically  (maybe destroyed at all)

Comment: did you get error at log ?

Comment: No errors or explanation why my activity is closed.

Comment: well in my application when i log in to facebook after i get the data the facebook application will suddenly close but then i get data and use it. but if i want to check user authorization i used state onSessionStateChange.

Comment: Have you added this to your AndroidManifest.xml?

        <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"

Answer (score 0):

Use UiLifeCycleHelper class to change the status of your session.

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);
        uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(this, callback);
        uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
```