# Facebook api hangs at "Opening" during openActiveSession

Tags: android, facebook

I can log in fine the first time.  And I have an option where the user can disable facebook within the android application.  When this is selected the facebook status goes to CLOSED.  When I use the option again, to log back in the API hangs at OPENING within the callback function.

Per the examples I've found the first call uses

```
session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(activity).setCallback(statusCallback));
```

and the second uses

```
Session.openActiveSession(activity, true, statusCallback);
```

The callback function looks like this:

```
private static class SessionStatusCallback implements Session.StatusCallback {
    // callback when session changes state
    @Override
    public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        if (session.isOpened()) {
            // make request to the /me API
            Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
                // callback after Graph API response with user object
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                    if (user != null) {
                        GlobalVars.setUser(user.getName());
                        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(GlobalVars.getContext());
                        Editor editor = prefs.edit();
                        editor.putBoolean("facebook", true);
                        editor.commit();
                        System.out.println("facebook logged in");
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        System.out.println("facebook session state callback " + session.getState().toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: I currently have the same problem. Can't open a session. It shows loading forever. And when I back out, it says I canceled it. The same code worked a few days ago. Seems like a facebook problem to me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not sure if we have the exact problem, but my facebook's session state retains "OPENING" after the `Session.openActiveSession(activity, true, statusCallback);`. I had overridden the `onActivityResult()` inside my fragment. What I did to solve this was to override the method on my Activity instead.

Related answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13888652/782870