# <Ignore This Q>Android Facebook UserSettingsFragment session status stuck at OPENING

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

**I realise this is a stupid question and needs to be deleted but stackoverflow wont let me since it has answers**

I am trying to implement Login with facebook in my app using the UserSettingsFragment. The session status seems to be stuck at OPENING. It never moves on to OPEN. I have instantiated the fragment as follows

```
if(userSettingsFragment==null){
    userSettingsFragment=new UserSettingsFragment();
    Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
    if(session==null || session.isClosed()){
        userSettingsFragment.setPublishPermissions(Arrays.asList("publish_actions"));
    }
    userSettingsFragment.setSessionStatusCallback(new Session.StatusCallback(){
        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
            Log.i("LoginUsingFBMain", String.format("New session state: %s", state.toString()));
        }
    });
}
fragment=userSettingsFragment;
.
.
.
getFragmentManager().popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

and I also have code in place to catch the login result.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(
        int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(userSettingsFragment != null)
        userSettingsFragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);     


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. My Hash was incorrect. A newer version of the sdk actually gave me an error message.

Answer (score 0):

Have you overridden the onActivityResult() method inside the fragment?  Try moving it to the Activity instead.

[Facebook api hangs at "Opening" during openActiveSession](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15194887/facebook-api-hangs-at-opening-during-openactivesession)

Comment: No it is the method in the activity. I already saw that post. :(